# Python 3.5 Type Error Comparing Int to List

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a pretty simple script for my intro to python class. The script will eventually automate dice rolls for the board game Risk. It is still early on in its development, but I have run into a type error I do not entirely understand. The two variables should both be lists as they are generated by the same basic code, yet it returns a type error. Here is the code I have done so far:

```
print ("Please input Attacking number and defending number, in that order.")
def numdiceroll(x, y):
    import random
    sides = 6
    attacking = x
    defending = y
    if attacking >= 3 and defending >= 2:
        dicea = random.sample(range(1, sides + 1), 3)
        print (dicea)
        diced = random.sample(range(1, sides +1), 2)
        print (diced)
        if max(dicea) > max(diced) and min(dicea) > (diced):
            print ("Attacker Wins Both")
        if max(dicea) > max(diced) and min(dicea) < (diced):
            print ("Both Lose 1")
        if max(dicea) < max(diced) and min(dicea) > (diced):
            print ("Both Lose 1")
        if max(dicea) < max(diced) and min(dicea) < (diced):
            print ("Defender Wins Both")
```

Comment: on which line is the error coming? can you show how you are taking the input?

Comment: Oops, it would help if I added the error. A bit tired.

if max(dicea) > max(diced) and min(dicea) > (diced):

This is the line the error is occurring in. An answer below pointed out that it is due to comparing a list to a number. I wanted the min and max commands to pull the min/max numbers from the list and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
min(dicea) > (diced)
```

`diced` is a list, and min and max return numbers. You cannot compare a number with a list. Now it depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was wanting the min/max functions to pull the numbers from the lists and compare them. Because in risk you compare high rolls with high rolls and low rolls with low rolls to discern who wins that battle.